# sendgrid html overwrties text while smtplib does not

Tags: python, html, text, sendgrid

when i use sendgrid python library

and use both

```
message.set_text('Body')
message.set_html('<html><body>Stuff, you know?</body></html>')
```

I see that html over writes text.
If I use smtplib I am able to have both text and html part in the email.
any solution to achieve same in sendgrid ?

Comment: Where do you see it is being overridden?

Comment: in the message i receive. If i do not set_html ..then i see "body" and if i do set_html i see"stuff, you know"..adn then the unsubscribe message

Comment: I think it's about how your email client reads the message.

Comment: email client is gmail

Comment: to be precise this is what i see on gmail in first case

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid will correctly deliver the HTML as an 'Alternative' body for the text email.

If your email client supports HTML email bodies, and HTML is provided, then HTML will "override" the text. If your client doesn't support HTML then it can show the text version accordingly.

This is likely the desired behaviour.

I suspect that when you're using 'smtplib' you're not properly specifying Multipart content for the HTML and Text content. Here's a good example of how to send MIMEMultipart content using smtplib:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id5

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, `html` and `text` are [set on the `message` instance](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/sendgrid/message.py#L101-L105) and [sent in the message body separately](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/sendgrid/sendgrid.py#L64-L65). They do not override each other.